# Why onMeasure is not called in these source code

Tags: android, android-view

In the Android source code, there is this block representing when `onMeasure` shouldn't not be called, which means after the first measure, if the following condition is met, `onMeasure` is not called.

```java
// Optimize layout by avoiding an extra EXACTLY pass when the view is
// already measured as the correct size. In API 23 and below, this
// extra pass is required to make LinearLayout re-distribute weight.

//my understanding: parent measure mode or height/width is changed
final boolean specChanged = widthMeasureSpec != mOldWidthMeasureSpec
                || heightMeasureSpec != mOldHeightMeasureSpec;

//my understanding: parent measure mode is Exactly
final boolean isSpecExactly = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                && MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

//my understanding: last current(child) view measurement is the same as parent measurement
final boolean matchesSpecSize = getMeasuredWidth() == MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
                && getMeasuredHeight() == MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);


final boolean needsLayout = specChanged
                && (sAlwaysRemeasureExactly || !isSpecExactly || !matchesSpecSize);
```

In my understanding, `widthMeasureSpec` is the parent measure spec. According to the source code, if parent measure mode is `Exact` and its width and height are changed, the child doesn't need to re-measure.

That doesn't make sense to me, if child is `match_parent`, even if parent is exact, when its width or height changed, the child needs to match and change as well. Do I miss something?

Comment: Are you meaning `layout` or `measure`? As I see the last variable is `needsLayout`

Comment: If child is `match_parent`, its measure mode is `EXACTLY`, and only if the parent's width / height has not changed, the `specChanged = widthMeasureSpec != mOldWidthMeasureSpec
                || heightMeasureSpec != mOldHeightMeasureSpec` could return true

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. If parent's width or height changed, then specChanged is true. If child is `match_parent`, then isSpecExactly is true. so in this case, it needs calculate layout again, is it because matchesSpecSize is false?

Comment: I think you're right. Only if the `getMeasuredWidth()` in above code called before its `onMeasure`, because after onMeasure it is very possible it matches the parent size.